Integration of drake to OpenSUSE - external/lcm/lcm-gen: error: libmpi.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
This is a follow-up to this
While I think I have solved the problem that mpi.h wasn't found in the last question by installing mumps-openmpi4-devel which includes MUMPS 5.3.5, I can't get around the following error (even though I exported the location of libmpi.so.40 beforehand):
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> find /usr -name mpicc
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicc
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> export MPI_HOME=/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> export PATH=$MPI_HOME/bin:$PATH
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> which mpicc
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicc
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> which mpicxx
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicxx
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.' ! -name 'bazel.rc.in' ! -name 'WORKSPACE.in' ! -name 'modules' ! -name 'external' -exec rm -rf {} +
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> ls
WORKSPACE.in  bazel.rc.in  external  modules
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/lib64:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/lib64:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/lib64:/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib:
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> find /usr -name libmpi.so.40
/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/lib64/libmpi.so.40
dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> cmake .. -DWITH_USER_FMT:BOOLEAN=ON -DWITH_USER_SPDLOG:BOOLEAN=ON -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicxx - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:60 (message):
  Could NOT find the lsb_release executable


-- Found Bazel: /usr/local/bin/bazel (Required is at least version "5.1") 
-- Found Python: /home/dan/.pyenv/shims/python3.10 (found suitable exact version "3.10.0") found components: Development Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.35.3") 
fatal: not a git repository: /home/dan/drake/../.git/modules/drake
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Reading 'startup' options from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc: --output_base=/home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --enable_bzlmod=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --announce_rc=no --repo_env=CC=/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicc --repo_env=CXX=/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi4/bin/mpicxx
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'build' options: -c opt --strip=never --strict_system_includes --cxxopt=-std=c++20 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++20 --test_output=errors --test_summary=terse --test_tag_filters=-gurobi,-mosek,-snopt --test_env=DISPLAY --test_env=GRB_LICENSE_FILE --test_env=MOSEKLM_LICENSE_FILE --test_env=LCM_DEFAULT_URL=memq:// --test_env=MPLBACKEND=Template
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/tools/ubuntu.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --force_pic --fission=dbg --features=per_object_debug_info --action_env=PATH=/usr/bin:/bin --action_env=PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 --test_env=PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
INFO: Reading rc options for 'info' from /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --symlink_prefix=/ --color=yes --subcommands=no --package_path=%workspace%:/home/dan/drake --notrim_test_configuration --action_env=CCACHE_DISABLE=1 --config=Release
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:Release in file /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd/.bazelrc: --compilation_mode=opt
bazel-bin: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin
bazel-genfiles: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin
bazel-testlogs: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs
character-encoding: file.encoding = ISO-8859-1, defaultCharset = ISO-8859-1
command_log: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/command.log
committed-heap-size: 719MB
execution_root: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake
gc-count: 5
gc-time: 44ms
install_base: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/install/117cee491f5c7d83be6e3c6d6b5b8ca4
java-home: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/install/117cee491f5c7d83be6e3c6d6b5b8ca4/embedded_tools/jdk
java-runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-LTS) by Azul Systems, Inc.
java-vm: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode) by Azul Systems, Inc.
max-heap-size: 8304MB
output_base: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3
output_path: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/execroot/drake/bazel-out
package_path: %workspace%:/home/dan/drake
release: release 6.4.0
repository_cache: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dan/cache/repos/v1
server_log: /home/dan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_/7ea85213ca47cc67b02970ecea7788b3/java.log.a512920a153a.dan.log.java.20240416-143926.1291
server_pid: 1291
used-heap-size: 124MB
workspace: /home/dan/drake/cmake/drake_build_cwd
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dan/drake/cmake

dan@a512920a153a:~/drake/cmake> make install
INFO: Analyzed target //:install (55 packages loaded, 14100 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/dan/drake/lcmtypes/BUILD.bazel:289:23: Action lcmtypes/drake/experimental_lcmt_deformable_tri.java failed: (Exit 127): lcm-gen failed: error executing command (from target //lcmtypes:lcmtypes_drake_java_lcm_library_gen) bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/lcm/lcm-gen --java '--jpath=bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/lcmtypes' lcmtypes/experimental_lcmt_deformable_tri.lcm ... (remaining 49 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/lcm/lcm-gen: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/dan/drake/lcmtypes/BUILD.bazel:289:23 Building lcmtypes/liblcmtypes_drake_java.jar (50 source files) failed: (Exit 127): lcm-gen failed: error executing command (from target //lcmtypes:lcmtypes_drake_java_lcm_library_gen) bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/lcm/lcm-gen --java '--jpath=bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/lcmtypes' lcmtypes/experimental_lcmt_deformable_tri.lcm ... (remaining 49 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
INFO: Elapsed time: 51.694s, Critical Path: 7.94s
INFO: 496 processes: 238 internal, 258 processwrapper-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/build.make:70: CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:839: CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2


This is the Dockerfile that I used:
# Use OpenSUSE Leap 15.4 as base
FROM opensuse/leap:15.4

# Install vim, sudo, and other necessary tools and libraries for drake
RUN zypper --non-interactive update && \
    zypper --non-interactive install -y vim sudo git cmake make java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel \
    glib2-devel lapack-devel libX11-devel ocl-icd-devel opencl-headers patch patchelf \
    pkg-config python3-devel python3-pygame zlib-devel pkg-config eigen3-devel \
    gcc-fortran nasm wget unzip tar gzip 

# Install GCC 11
RUN zypper --non-interactive install -y gcc11 gcc11-c++

# Set GCC 11 as the default compiler
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 110 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc 35 && \
    update-alternatives --set cc /usr/bin/gcc && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++ 35 && \
    update-alternatives --set c++ /usr/bin/g++

# Download and build fmt with position-independent code
RUN wget https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/archive/refs/tags/8.1.1.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf 8.1.1.tar.gz && \
    cd fmt-8.1.1 && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=TRUE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local && \
    make && \
    sudo make install

# Download and build spdlog with position-independent code, using external fmt
RUN wget https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/archive/refs/tags/v1.10.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf v1.10.0.tar.gz && \
    cd spdlog-1.10.0 && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=TRUE -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local && \
    make && \
    sudo make install

# Install Bazelisk
RUN curl -L https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.7.5/bazelisk-linux-amd64 > /usr/local/bin/bazelisk && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bazelisk && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/bazelisk /usr/local/bin/bazel

# Download and place jchart2d-3.3.2.jar in /usr/share/java/jchart2d.jar
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jchart2d/jchart2d/3.3.2/jchart2d-3.3.2.jar -O /usr/share/java/jchart2d.jar

# Create .pc files for LAPACK and BLAS
RUN echo -e "prefix=/usr\nexec_prefix=\${prefix}\nlibdir=\${exec_prefix}/lib64\nincludedir=\${prefix}/include\n\nName: LAPACK\nDescription: Linear Algebra Package\nVersion: 3.9.0\nLibs: -L\${libdir} -llapack\nCflags: -I\${includedir}" > /usr/share/pkgconfig/lapack.pc && \
    echo -e "prefix=/usr\nexec_prefix=\${prefix}\nlibdir=\${exec_prefix}/lib64\nincludedir=\${prefix}/include\n\nName: BLAS\nDescription: Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms\nVersion: 3.9.0\nLibs: -L\${libdir} -lblas\nCflags: -I\${includedir}" > /usr/share/pkgconfig/blas.pc

# Set up the environment for user 'dan'
RUN groupadd -r dan && \
    useradd -m -s /bin/bash -r -g dan dan && \
    mkdir -p /home/dan/drake && \
    chown -R dan:dan /home/dan/drake && \
    echo "dan ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER dan
ENV HOME /home/dan
WORKDIR $HOME

# Install dependencies for pyenv and Python build
RUN sudo zypper --non-interactive install -y git gcc make zlib-devel libbz2-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel \
    sqlite3-devel python3-clang15 clang15-devel

# Install pyenv and Python 3.10
RUN git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git $HOME/.pyenv && \
    echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"\nfi' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc && pyenv install 3.10.0 && pyenv global 3.10.0"

# Ensure the selected Python version 3.10 is used and install PyYAML
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.bashrc && pyenv rehash && pip install PyYAML"

# Set environment variables for GCC to ensure Bazel uses the correct version
ENV CC=/usr/bin/gcc-11
ENV CXX=/usr/bin/g++-11
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/lib/cmake:${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}

RUN sudo zypper --non-interactive install -y mumps-openmpi4-devel

Is this problem shown above with version 5.3.5 a fixable problem with changes/modifications on the side of drake (that would be good news) or is there a fundamental hard-to-fix incompatibilty with MUMPS version 5.3.5 (I would then try it without 5.3.5)?
I am asking the question in this way, because I observed that for OpenSUSE 15.4 MUMPS packages are mostly of version 5.3.5 while in the previous question the stub file for version  5.4.1 was shown. However, the compilation of MUMPS 5.4.1 on OpenSUSE 15.4 is troublesome and I wanted to check this and ask for your opinion before I go further.
